# Drag and Drop files in DropArea and upload it through form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html

I unable to get the file details in form post,

```
<form action="/FileUpload/SaveDefault" id="form0" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" encoding="multipart/form-data">
  <input class="uploader" type="file" data-role="none" name="UploadDefault" multiple="multiple">
  <input type="submit" value="save">
</form>
```

In drag area, once i drag and dropped a file there, the drop event got triggered, there i get the file details and set to the input field through 'prop'.

I have bound drop event,

```
onDropHandler: function (e) {                
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
  $("input[type='file']").prop("files", e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files);
}
```

In code behind, (form post)

```
public ActionResult SaveDefault(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> UploadDefault,ImageDetails datas)
{
  foreach (var file in datas.UploadDefault)
  {
    string fileName = file.FileName ;
  }
}
```

These logic working fine in Chrome, but breaking in IE. Where did I make the mistake?

Comment: Are you sure this is working? I ask as you should not be able to amend the `FileList` of a file input. It would be a browser bug if it allows this behaviour. What you're trying to do should not be allowed at all.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, Yes, it allowed in Chrome, But IE not allowing, Why it should not be allowed at all? Is there any specific reason?

Comment: The standards for FileList objects state that those generated from file inputs should be readonly: https://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#dfn-filelist `The HTMLInputElement interface has a readonly attribute of type FileList. Other interfaces with a readonly attribute of type FileList include the DataTransfer interface.`